# jquery/CSS rotate hides half of the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I want to be able to rotate an image in 4 steps if the user want it, but i'm having problems since the rotation i use centers the image and then hides half of the image when i just want the image to align to the left and to the top, even when rotated. I've used this script [jqueryRotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) and to see what I mean i've made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sqnsA/

As you see it aligns the image to the center when rotating it vertical, is there a way with css or javascript to make it align to top and to the left. This is my javascript:

```
var angle = 0;
$('#rotate').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (angle === 0) {
        $("#rotation").rotate(90);
    }
    if (angle === 1) {
        $("#rotation").rotate(180);
    }
    if (angle === 2) {
        $("#rotation").rotate(270);
    }
    if (angle === 3) {
        $("#rotation").rotate(360);
        angle = -1;
    }

    angle++;

});
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div style="position: relative;top: 0px;left: 0px;" id="rotation">
<img src="myimage.jpg" style="position: relative;max-height: 275px;max-width: 356px;" id="rotan"/>
</div>

<a href="" id="rotate">Rotate</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 4 solutions.

But first, let me explain your problem. When using css transform. there is a property called `transform-origin` wich is the point where the transformation occur. Its like if you put your figger on a sheet and rotate that sheet, your figger will be the rotation center.

Now you are rotating a `div` wich is a `display:block`. That mean it has 100% width and the height is equal to his content. Knowing that the default `transform-origin` value is 50%, that's why it rotate like that.

Now, the 4 solutions :

1. Set the div `display` to `inline-block`. That will adjust the width to its content.
2. Calculate the origin point to be in the center of the image.
3. Rotate the image
4. Make the div float

Here some information about [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Ftransform-origin).

Comment: There's a fifth option. Setting `transform-origin` to `top left`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/bikiew/sqnsA/1/

```
<div style="position: relative;top: 0px;left: 0px; width:365px;" id="rotation">
```

I fixed the width of your div "rotation" to be the same than your image.

Comment: Close, but as you can see when it's vertical it still doesn't align to the left and part of the image is above the div (<body>), i want it to be in the same position all the time but rotating if you understand what i mean?